# Update the geometry of a point through WFS-T

Tags: geoserver, wfs-t, geoserver-rest-api

I am trying to change a point geometry in a postgis table through geoserver.
I use python Requests in order to make the POST request.

My xml looks like this:

```
xmlstr = """<wfs:Transaction service="WFS" version="1.1.0"
             xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs"
             xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml"
             xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
            <wfs:Update>
             <wfs:Property>
              <wfs:Name>the_geom</wfs:Name>
              <wfs:Value>
               <Point srsName="http://www.opengis.net/gml/srs/epsg.xml#4326">
                <coordinates>-155.7421875 -11.178401873711785</coordinates>
               </Point>
              </wfs:Value>
             </wfs:Property>
            <ogc:Filter>
           <ogc:FeatureId fid="wld_nhr_adameqepic14days_wfp_test_1_1_1.2"/>
          </ogc:Filter>
         </wfs:Update>
        </wfs:Transaction>"""
```

When I send the request as:

```
requests.post(url, data=xmlstr, headers=headers, auth=('user', 'pass')).text
```

I get back the following error:

```
<ows:ExceptionReport xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:ows="http://www.opengis.net/ows" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="1.0.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/ows http://localhost:8080/geoserver/schemas/ows/1.0.0/owsExceptionReport.xsd">
```

java.lang.NullPointerException

I also tried to run the above through the Demos page of geoserver. I get also the same error: java.lang.NullPointerException

Ofcource none of the points are updated.
Any idea what is going on? Do I have a mistake on my XML structure?
I have also checked the WFS OGC documentation and it seems like my XML structure is correct.

**EDIT**

I have also executed the DesribeFeature for this layer. I see that the_geom attribute is there as:

```
<xsd:extension base="gml:AbstractFeatureType">
    <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="the_geom" nillable="true" type="gml:PointPropertyType"/>
      <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="fid" nillable="true" type="xsd:int"/>
      <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="time" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
      <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="latitude" nillable="true" type="xsd:double"/>
      <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="longi
```

Comment: Try to change the order of the coordinates. Maybe -155 degrees gets interpreted as south coordinate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the XML structure that worked after all:

```
<wfs:Transaction service="WFS" version="1.1.0"
  xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc"
  xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs"
  xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml">
<wfs:Update typeName="geonode:wld_nhr_adameqepic14days_wfp_test_1_1_1">
 <wfs:Property>
  <wfs:Name>the_geom</wfs:Name>
    <wfs:Value>
      <gml:Point srsName="http://www.opengis.net/gml/srs/epsg.xml#4326">
        <gml:pos>43.43 23.43</gml:pos>
     </gml:Point>
    </wfs:Value>
</wfs:Property>
<ogc:Filter>
  <ogc:FeatureId fid="wld_nhr_adameqepic14days_wfp_test_1_1_1.2"/>
 </ogc:Filter>
</wfs:Update>
</wfs:Transaction>
```

After checking the DescribeFeature, it was clear I need to add the gml namespace.